# Wordpress sum taxonomies with specific slug

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I count the taxonomies to get a sum? Let me explain better, I have to add the gold, silver and bronze medals of an athlete with the taxonomies, but the problem arises when this athlete has more than one equal medal, wordpress does not allow you to add two identical taxonomies, so if I change the slug I will have reached mine purpose, but how can I make a sum of gold, gold-2, gold-3?

Comment: **gold, silver, and bronze** are they your taxonomy terms or taxonomies? can you also explain with an example when this **equal medal** condition comes?

Comment: it is indifferent because I have yet to create the taxonomy, I must have as a final goal a total count of how many gold, silver and bronze medals are present.  If I have 100 athletes, with gold medals by adding a gold tag I have the total number of athletes with the gold medal, but so the athletes who have 2 or 3 gold medals are not counted.

Comment: Why don't you make it simple by using custom meta fields instead of taxonomies?

Comment: wordpress does not allow you to insert identical tags otherwise I would have solved it or I just enter the slug gold, gold-two, gold-three and then find a way to make a sum.

Comment: because I started using only gutenberg and didn't enable custom fields.  Because I'm not the only one running the site so I made it as simple as possible.  But looking back with the custom fields how could I do?  I must have a total sum of gold, silver and bronze.

Comment: You can install the **ACF** plugin, can create 3 or more number input fields for your post type and you can define how many gold, silver, etc medals the player has, you can also have total medals input as well or you can make a dynamic calculation with code using those custom fields.